# How to allow the Concept of Circularity in a program without infinite computational resources?

Tags: c#, circular-reference

This might sound like a very strange question. But i work on a project which needs to have cirular references within it. Actually, they are even non-avoidable. Because Users could create their own circular references within the GUI. And this is absolutely intended.... Please don't ask why, this would take ages to explain.

All Question, Answers, Resources i found which discuss Circular References provide Solutions and Approaches on how to avoid one. But non i have read contained a solution on how to make one, without killing the underlying computational resources.

**Issues i see**

Such a cicular reference seems to me to always have the possibility to completely overhelm the underlying system, be it a simple home computer or research supercomputer where this program is meant to be run.

This is due to my understanding that the resources provided are always finite, but circular references are infinite by nature.

The resources i see which might be of issue here are:

- computational power (CPU)
- working memory (RAM)
- Data storage
- Network bandwidth

**How could it be possible to mitigate those issues**

Mitigation could take place by making sure that the program itself is only ever able to increase it's needs for computational resources in an very minor and incremental fashion. If there are then measures implemented which, based on gathered Data of the whole System as a Unit, allows us to decide if further evolutions are even necessary to improve the perceived Quality of the System. It would help us to cap the needs for Computational Resources.

One of the ways i could imagine that this capping could take place is by introducing time as a limiting factor. The program could be designed in such a way that it only considers re-evaluating "itself" after a given amount of time. If this time and the limit of Quality are carefully choosen to match the underlying computational resources, i feel like the resource issues with circular references could be mitigated.

**Code Snippet**

Find below a very simplified Code Snippet. Point 1 and Point 2 are completely independent in nature, they could even be on different Threads (actually that's an Idea how it could be done, but i dont understand multithreading well enough to decide if it would be a good approach or not). The action first begins when they are attached to another. I do not care if the behavior of "First this then that" happens in a specific way. The only thing for which i do care is that all interactions between those two Points have been taken place at some point in the future (after their attachement).

```
namespace Circularity
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Point Point1 = new Point();
            Point Point2 = new Point();
            Point1.attach(Point2);
        }
    }
    class Point
    {
        private ulong Value;

        public Point()
        {
            Value = ulong.MaxValue / 2;
        }

        public void attach(Point otherPoint)
        {
            if (Value < ulong.MaxValue) Value++;
            otherPoint.attach(this);
        }
    }
}
```

This Code leads instantly to a Stack Overflow. But i do not understand the underlying concepts of the Stack well enough to implement a counter measure. I tried to apply the Time concept here already, but it just takes longer for the Stack Overflow.

Comment: In any cases, the solution has to be extremely scalable. One such Point could even be it's own microservice running in the cloud.

Comment: There is no counter measure to avoid this. When you call `Point1.Attach()`, `Attach()` recursively calls `Attach()` in `Point2`. This `Attach()` then calls `Attach()` in `Point1` again, and the cycle starts all over. Theoretically there's a point where this would stop, but `Value` = 18,446,744,073,709,551,615 / 2 and both points must reach `ulong.MaxValue()` before the Attach recursion stops. You'll long overflow the stack before you reach `MaxValue()`. You'll need to provide more detail, perhaps a more concrete example, and implement your solution another way.

Comment: Can you describe, in words, what you would like the function `attach` to do?  I can't understand at all what you are getting at with this block of text:  _I do not care if the behavior of "First this then that" happens in a specific way. The only thing for which i do care is that all interactions between those two Points have been taken place at some point in the future (after their attachement)._

Comment: The project is basically a Feedback loop. Point1 does something (in this case attaching), then Point 2 provides Feedback based on Point1s action and internal Data. This Feedback in turn is interpreted by Point2 as an action of Point1, it interprets it and provides again feedback. and so on..... What would be okay is if the time it takes for any point to provide his feedback is increased (basically to infinity) the closer Value is to ulong.MaxValue or ulong.MinValue

Comment: But the underlying resources should never actually be crashed.... It seems that's a real issue.

Comment: The caller would pop the next pair to be attached off a queue and call attach on them.  The implementation of attach pushes any future attach operations onto that queue (but doesn't actually call _attach_ itself).  Nibble away at the queue as often as you like.

Comment: I don't understand what you are looking for in this question as you said any detection/prevention of circular references is not what you are interested in... Systems with positive feedback loop and without natural bounds always explode... so again not sure how that infinite loop is an example of good behavior you want to achieve.

Comment: There is possibility that you are asking about "Sandboxing" rogue code which is different topic covering such infinite loops as result of general restriction on resource consumption... (Side note: Also assuming you've studied graph algorithms you know that many of them deal with loops perfectly fine... some notes on it in the question could help)

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I'm getting the vibe that it's more about the fact that with tail recursion this would not stack-overflow, it would just infinite loop.  It seems to be about how to formulate this program with similar syntax but without overflowing your stack.

Comment: @Wyck infinite loop *definitely* not going to consume "infinite computation resources" :)... but maybe... OP can easily [edit] to clarify...

Comment: wait...Do you think this terminates even with infinite memory?  Because it doesn't.  `attach` always calls another `attach` regardless of the `Value` the way you've written it.  Did you mean to have an `else` or a preemptive `return` or something?

Comment: I will edit the question as soon as i have clearly understood the answer from Matt. It seems to be able to solve all the Problems i have in my application right now. Fill make the question more clear afterwards.

Answer (score 2):

The reason you're getting a stack overflow is because you're calling `attach` recursively, so you will just keep adding stack frames, the CLR can't handle that many and as you've witnessed, it quickly maxes out. One strategy here would be to use Continuation Passing Style so you avoid building a stack of method calls.

[When and how to use continuation passing style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1309282/when-and-how-to-use-continuation-passing-style)

Comment: This seems to be exactly what i was looking for. Need to dive into it.